# jQueryAce won't work inside a hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a tabbed content on my website, and one of the tabs needs to contain the jQueryAce editor. I am following the example on their [website](http://cheef.github.io/jquery-ace/), like below:

```
<textarea class="my-code-area" rows="4" style="width: 100%">puts 'foo'</textarea>
<script>
$('.my-code-area').ace({ theme: 'twilight', lang: 'ruby' })
</script>
```

These lines are meant to be inside a div which has `display: none` initially, until the user clicks the tab name. If they are inside that `div`, when it is shown, the editor will not be visible (also, won't work), but if the lines are outside the hidden `div` then the editor works pretty well.

Any advice about how I can put this editor in an initially hidden `div`?

Answer (score 1):

Then you should initialize your plugin after showing the main div like,

```
$('your-div').show();
$('.my-code-area').ace({theme:'twilight',lang:'ruby'}); // add after showing parent div
```